# Inversion in one to one region of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, inverse, monotone-functions

Suppose I have a polynomial: $P(x)=x-x^3$ defined for $x\in[0,1]$. Plot of $P(x)$ over this range of $x$ shows that each value of $P$ corresponds to two different values of $x$ (the curve is concave downward, beginning and ending at zero), except at the peak value of the curve, $\hat{P}$, which occurs at $x=1/\sqrt{3}$. Now if I limit $x$ to the interval $[0,1/\sqrt{3}]$, I have a one-to-one correspondence between $P$ and $x$. I was wondering if I can invert the polynomial in this limited region to obtain $x(P)$. My ultimate aim is to obtain $\frac{dx}{dP}$ in this region. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x-x^3=y$ is a [cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Algebraic_solution). It can be solved by algebraic means, but the answer does not look pretty:
$$
x=-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(\sqrt{81 y^2-12}+9 y\right)^{2/3}+2 \sqrt[3]{3}}{6^{2/3}
   \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{81 y^2-12}+9 y}}.
$$
You can find the derivative by implicit differentiation:
$$
(3\,x^2-1)\,\frac{dx}{dy}=1.
$$

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot. General solution of this equation consists of one real function and two conjugate complex functions. So you have picked the real function. From your answer it seems to me that the real function solution represents the one-to-one branch of the $y(x)$ curve. Would this be applicable to a general cubic polynomial?

Comment: In fact, when $|y|<2\sqrt3/9$, there are three real valued branches. When $|y|>2\sqrt3/9$ there is a real valued branch and two complex branches. And yes, you can treat any cubic polynomial like this. In certain cases it will be 1 tp 1 on all $\Bbb R$.